# wamp server apache phpmyadmin and database access fail

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

My problem started with a single upgrade for the wamp server.
Sence that I'm unable to access most of my database.

wamp server:
apache 2.4.2
apache 2.4.4
php 5.4.12 - not working at all, has a warning sign
php 5.4.3
mysql 5.5.24 
mysql 5.6.12

First of all phmyadmin has crashed, so I've started googling. Found some promising solution like:
changeing phpmyadmin.cong file to

```
<Directory "C:/Program Files/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
    Require host localhost
    Require local
</Directory>
```

With this it is now possible to run apache 2.4.**4** but not 2.4.**2**.
But with 2.4.4 I'm not able to access my databases, except 2.

Is there a way atleast to save my databaes without phpmyadmin?

Comment: Wamp server comes bundled with it's own mysql server which is why you can't access one from the other. I would think you can copy the data files from the previous wamp install or you could edit the mysql location within the new my.ini file. I haven't done it before so I can only comment on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say your phpMyAdmin crashed. It's just a web application, so normally if it encounters trouble connecting to the MySQL server it will give an error message. If the PHP interpreter or Apache server have problems, those would generally be recorded in the log file. I suggest you look through your Apache and MySQL error logs to see if there's a hint about what's going on. Do you get an error message or is it just a blank screen?

You can save your databases without phpMyAdmin by using the MySQL utility `mysqldump`. I use it to generate SQL dump files of my databases for backup with `mysqldump databasename -u root > databasename.sql` (though that's on Linux I believe the exact same syntax works on Windows, as long as mysqldump is in your path).

Also as Dan stated, it's strange for you to have two MySQL servers of different versions installed, it could be that there's a conflict there.